# Group by calculation with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df below as

Sample df:

```
City   | Name | Purchase
Texas    Bob      0 
Texas    Ken      4
Florida  Ben      1
Texas    Red      18
Florida  Ken      55
Florida  Ted      0
```

How can I calculate the % that each city has a person with 3 or more purchases / all people in that city?

So formula would be people with 3+ purchases / all people in that city

Expected output:

```
City   |  %
Texas    .67
Florida  .33
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mean` on the condition to find that percentage, and also combine with `groupby` to calculate for each city

```
df['Purchase'].ge(3).groupby(df['City']).mean()
```

Output:

```
City
Florida    0.333333
Texas      0.666667
Name: Purchase, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thnx, what goes the ge function do?

Comment: @Chris90 that's a shorthand for `greater than or equal to`, same with `df['Purchase'] >=3`.

Comment: Was just working on this one myself - but nowhere near this simple. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang